# "You may fetch vote counts once every second" looks redundant

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, vote-count

Turns out if one quickly clicks more than once on vote count area (or there's come network lug and so the user feels "it didn't work" and clicks again promptly) there's a message "you may fetch vote count once every second" right into user face

[image]

Now the limit of no more than one fetch per second is okay, no problem with is. But what's the point of the message? I mean if over the course of one second I intentionally or accidentally click the votes are twice and the vote count is just returned to me once - what do I lose? Will I even note the difference?

With the current implementation there's this message shown right into the user's face that has absolutely no value to him.

Shouldn't the second fetch just be silently ignored?

Comment: I had never seen that before your post. It should probably be removed.

Comment: How about we replace it with a "Stop it with your damn clicking already!!"? ;)

Comment: @Bart: What we currently have is not that far from what you suggest.

Comment: I'm with Bart on this one

Comment: New text should be: `Patience Daniel-san`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with the next build, fetching the vote count split will only allow one request to be in flight at once.  Extra clicks will be ignored.